# how does unix handle full path name with space and arguments?

Tags: unix, path

How does unix handle full path name with space and arguments ?
In windows we quote the path and add the command-line arguments after, how is it in unix?

```
 "c:\foo folder with space\foo.exe" -help
```

**update:**

I meant how do I recognize a path from the command line arguments.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "recognise a path from the command line arguments"? Might be worth starting a new question as everyone has answered the first part.

Answer (score 43):

You can either quote it like your Windows example above, or escape the spaces with backslashes:

```
 "/foo folder with space/foo" --help
 /foo\ folder\ with\ space/foo --help
```

Comment: I think you meant "escape the spaces"

Comment: in addition, at times, you may want to enclose the whole path with quotation marks, such as: "/foo\ folder\ with\ space/foo"

Answer (score 11):

You can quote if you like, or you can escape the spaces with a preceding \, but most UNIX paths (Mac OS X aside) don't have spaces in them.

```
/Applications/Image\ Capture.app/Contents/MacOS/Image\ Capture

"/Applications/Image Capture.app/Contents/MacOS/Image Capture"

/Applications/"Image Capture.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Image Capture"
```

All refer to the same executable under Mac OS X.

I'm not sure what you mean about recognizing a path - if any of the above paths are passed as a parameter to a program the shell will put the entire string in one variable - you don't have to parse multiple arguments to get the entire path.

Answer (score 4):

Since spaces are used to separate command line arguments, they have to be escaped from the shell.  This can be done with either a backslash () or quotes:

```
"/path/with/spaces in it/to/a/file"
somecommand -spaced\ option
somecommand "-spaced option"
somecommand '-spaced option'
```

This is assuming you're running from a shell.  If you're writing code, you can usually pass the arguments directly, avoiding the problem:

Example in perl.  Instead of doing:

`print("code sample");`system("somecommand -spaced option");

you can do

`print("code sample");`system("somecommand", "-spaced option");

Since when you pass the system() call a list, it doesn't break arguments on spaces like it does with a single argument call.

Answer (score 2):

Also be careful with double-quotes -- on the Unix shell this expands variables.  Some are obvious (like `$foo` and `\t`) but some are not (like `!foo`).

For safety, use single-quotes!

Answer (score 1):

You can quote the entire path as in windows or you can escape the spaces like in:

```
/foo\ folder\ with\ space/foo.sh -help
```

Both ways will work!

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to point out that in case you are using command line arguments as part of a shell script (.sh file), then within the script, you would need to enclose the argument in quotes. So if your command looks like

```
>scriptName.sh arg1 arg2
```

And arg1 is your path that has spaces, then within the shell script, you would need to refer to it as "$arg1" instead of $arg1

[Here are the details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If the normal ways don't work, trying substituting spaces with `%20`.

This worked for me when dealing with SSH and other domain-style commands like `auto_smb`.