# Handle Spaces in File Path Unix programmatically

Tags: c, unix, freebsd

I'm trying to open files at random from my disk. Problem Is Most have Spaces in their path and won't
open unless I add backslashes on the fly, which is proving more difficult than I thought. While doing research I saw 
[how does unix handle full path name with space and arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794/how-does-unix-handle-full-path-name-with-space-and-arguments)
which say's that you can use backslashes or quotes but that was referring to passing arguments to the shell. Is it possible to do something like...

```
 static int removeSpaces(char **inBuf, char **outBuf)
 {
     /* Declarations */
     int rtrn;
     char *pos;

     /* Null terminate incoming buffer */
     if((pos=strchr(*inBuf, '\n')) != NULL)
     {
         *pos = '\0';
     }

     rtrn = asprintf(outBuf, "\"%s\"", *inBuf);
     if(rtrn < 0)
     {
         printf("Memory Error\n");
         return -1;
     }
     return 0;
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     int rtrn;

     char *file, *parsed;

     rtrn = getFile(&file);
     if(rtrn < 0)
     {
         printf("Can't Get File\n");
         return -1;
     }

     rtrn = removeSpaces(&file, &parsed);
     if(rtrn < 0)
     {
         printf("Can't Get File\n");
         return -1;
     }

     printf("Parsed: %s\n", parsed);
     fd = open(parsed, O_RDONLY);
     if(fd < 0)
     {
         perror("Can't Open File\n");
         return -1;
     }
     return 0;      
}
```

I currently get no such file or directory, but i was wondering can I pass quoted file paths to open() or fopen(), or is that only the case with passing file paths to the shell. I'm asking because I saw very little information on the web specific to unix and unix-like systems, most was about windows (at least what i saw), and what i did find for unix was about the shell and not system calls.

Comment: Space in filenames shouldn't matter if you open the files with e.g `open` or `fopen`. If you add double-quotes to the string, you want to open a file with literal double-quotes in the file name.

Comment: let me double check because the open() call was failing, but when i copied the filename directly in with backslashes before the spaces it opens.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was not a question after all.

Comment: what about this question " but i was wondering can I pass quoted file paths to open() or fopen(), or is that only the case with passing file paths to the shell."

Comment: `removeSpaces()` does not remove spaces.  Instead it truncates upon finding a `'\n'` and the puts `'\"'` around the filename.

Comment: yea i know it doesn't remove spaces i just used the same function layout as another function named removeSpaces() that attempted to insert backslash in front of spaces.